# Calculating percentile - Excel vs online

Tags: excel, excel-formula, percentile, vba

I have a set of data say {4,7,7,10,10,12,12,14,15,67} and i want to know the 95th Percentile. I used Excel and Online calculator.

Both gave different answers.

In Excel, formula i used : `=PERCENTILE.INC(A1:A10,0.95)` and result = `43.6`

But this [online percentile calculator](https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/probability-statistics/percentile-calculator/?i=4%2C7%2C7%2C10%2C10%2C12%2C12%2C14%2C15%2C67&p=95&steps=on) yielded a result of `67`

Which one is right?

Comment: They both are right in the sense that they both implement the algorithm that they were designed to implement (using different definitions of "percentile", which can vary substantially for small samples). How could we know which one you want?

Comment: https://github.com/bluesmoon/node-faststats/issues/14

Comment: I want 67 as result in Excel. Which formula to use?

Comment: Personally, I think that 67 is the less principled one. The link that @TimWilliams gives is spot-on. Percentiles should use interpolation. Picking the endpoint as the 95th percentile is somewhat arbitrary. Your actual data doesn't actually *have* a 95th percentile. The only reasonable thing is to estimate the missing value.

Comment: The online calculator has an explanation of how they arrive at the result - follow that in excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, both methods are "right" in the sense that both implement a standard algorithm for computing percentiles. Unlike the mean or median (where all sources use the same approach) there are many different approaches to calculating percentiles. The fundamental issue is that there is no obvious solution to the problem of what to do with percentiles which fall between observations. Do you take the observed value which is closest? Do you interpolate between the two? If so -- with what weighting factors do you do the interpolation? [Wikipedia discusses nine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) (!) with both the Excel approach and the approach from that online percentile calculator making the list. See [this paper](https://www.amherst.edu/media/view/129116/original/Sample%2BQuantiles.pdf) for a very nice discussion of these algorithms.

You can replicate the functionality of that online percentile function like thus:

```
=SMALL(A1:A10,CEILING.MATH(COUNT(A1:A10)*0.95))
```

For example:

[image]

The point of using the function `SMALL` rather than a direct numerical index is that this approach works even if the data isn't sorted.